# Save and read multiple types of setting in a text file

Tags: java, list, generics, settings

I want to have a setting system that I can read write and use variables from the are stored in a file.
To summarize, There is a class and inside that class is a list of settings.
When I make a setting I want to add it to the list so that I can write it to the text file later.
I also want to be able to get the setting value without casting it which would use generics.
So for boolSetting I would only need to do boolSetting.get() or boolSetting.value ect

To start with code I have already written I have the code to read and write to the file. This works perfect (I think). I just need help with the setting part. Here is the read and write to file.

```
package winter.settings;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import net.minecraft.src.Config;
import winter.Client;

public class WinterSettings {
    
    public static File WinterSetting;

    
    
    public static void readSettings() {
        try {
            File WinterSetting = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "WinterSettings.txt");

            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(WinterSetting), "UTF-8"));
            
            String s = "";

            while ((s = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(s);
                String[] astring = s.split(":");

Client.modules.forEach(m ->{

    if(m.name==astring[0]) {
        m.settings.forEach(setting ->{

            if(setting.name==astring[1]) {
                setting.value=astring[2];
            }
        });
    }
});
            }
            bufferedreader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public static void writeSettings() {

        try {
            File WinterSetting = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "WinterSettings.txt");

            PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(WinterSetting));

Client.modules.forEach(m ->{
    
    m.settings.forEach(setting ->{
        
        printwriter.println(m.name+":"+setting.name+":"+setting.value);
        
    });
    
});
printwriter.close();
         
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Pretty much how this works is I have a setting in a Module which just stores some information.
The setting has a name and a value
To write it I am just writing

The module name, the setting name, the setting value For example: ModuleName:SettingName:false

This works fine, but leads to the problem that I just don't know enough about generics. I can't find a way that works with writing reading and setting / getting. The setting should have a name and value. Some code I wrote is below I just don't know how to continue it.

```
public class Setting<T> {

    public String name;
    public T value;

    public Setting(String name, T value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
return value;
}
    

    
}
```

From here I have subclasses for each type of setting. Not sure if this is good programming or not.
Now I can set get / write, but when I read the value isn't updated correctly.

Right now I make a new setting like

```
    private final BooleanSetting toggleSprint =  new BooleanSetting("ToggleSprint", true);
```

There is one problem to this from what I can tell. First off when I try to add it to a list when initilizing I get an error.
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to BooleanSetting.

In short: I need to be able to read write get and set a value in a setting object. This can be boolean / int / ect.

Above is some of my code to read / write to txt file. Setting class and what I have of making a new setting.

My 2 problems are that I read the settings correctly and when making them I can't add them to a list.

Comment: `if(setting.name==astring[1]) ` is not how you compare Strings in Java

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Boolean.True` static variable

```
new BooleanSetting("ToggleSprint", Boolean.TRUE);
```

or

```
Boolean.valueOf(true)
```

Comment: I still cant figure out how to correctly read the value and I dont think this will fix it but thanks

Comment: Sorry to be rude, but your question is full of non relevant stuff.  Please show what is not working. [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)